# python flask avoid function arguments which appear in route, but unnecessary

Tags: python, flask

I have function which mapped to some model related path, like this

```
@app.route('/models/<model_id>/something', methods=['GET'])
@fill_model
def my_function(user, model):
    do_something();
```

inside `@fill_model` decorator I read `model_id` from URL, and get model instance from database and pushing it to `my_function` but with that notation I get the following error `'my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_id'`

so I could add `model_id` to `my_function` but I don't really need it and it will spoil the code. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Of course I could change route from  to  and then it will be working fine, but I think it's a bit dirty solution

Comment: Can we see the code for `fill_model`?

Comment: Why you need it? It's just request model from db and put it to function argumenst like `args['model'] = Provider.get_model_from_db(model_id)`

Comment: Quite simply: because that's most likely where the problem is. My intuition is that you are not *removing* `model_id` from `kwargs` (you might simply be adding `model`), which explains why it still gets passed to your function. Seeing your code would let me confirm this intuition, or find something else. Now, *you* are the one who needs help here; you're free not to provide the code if you want, but you might not get a response if you don't.

Comment: Ok, you really right. I forget to remove it from the argument list. Please, put it as answer and I will mark it as accepted. But actually I don't think that it work that simple and just pushing all the stuff to the function, I think it's just check actual function signature and provide only existed elements.

Comment: No worries — glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case, my `fill_model` decorator just pushing all arguments to my function and `model_id` was in this arguments, but not in function signature. So what need to be done, it's just remove `model_id` from argument list passed to function inside decorator.

Correct answer provided in comment by @Thomas Orozco  Thanks a lot to him.